# Merge and Un-merge multiple models in Keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I have some sale data for various products (P1, P2, and P3) in different cities (A, B, C). I wish to develop a model for each product to predict their sales. Since I only have data for total sales in each city, I want to build a network that merges three sub-networks at the output layer. After training, I want to un-merge my model and obtain an individual model for each product. Based on the questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46397258/how-to-merge-sequential-models-in-keras-2-0), my code is like:

```
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras import layers
from keras import Input
# model for P1
input_p1 = Input(shape=(64,))
p1 = layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(input_p1)
p1 = layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(p1)
p1 = layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')(p1)
p1_sale = layers.Dense(1)(p1)

# model for P2
input_p2 = Input(shape=(64,))
p2 = layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(input_p2)
p2 = layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(p2)
p2 = layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')(p2)
p2_sale = layers.Dense(1)(p2)

# model for P3
input_p3 = Input(shape=(64,))
p3 = layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(input_p3)
p3 = layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(p3)
p3 = layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')(p3)
p3_sale = layers.Dense(1)(p3)

added = keras.layers.Add()([p1_sale, p2_sale, p3_sale])
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input_p1, input_p2, input_p3], outputs=added)
```

My question is how can we split the `added` model into three separate models for P1, P2, and P3 after I train it?